# How to check if the SAML Assertion Response from the IdP reaches the SP in Ping Federate?

Tags: saml-2.0, pingfederate

The SAML Response will be posted to the following url:

https://domain/sp/ACS.SAML2

But when I try to hit the url, I am not able to see the response. 
Anything wrong in my approach?

Thanks & Regards,
Aswini J

Answer (score 3):

A few things assuming you are setting up SAML 2.0 Web SSO Profile -

1. What do you mean you can't "see" the Response? Are you successfully logging into the IDP and having it redirect the Browser to the PF ACS URL?
2. With PingFederate, the application and protocol end-points are case sensitive. You should use `http(s)://www.server.com:<PF runtime port>/sp/ACS.saml2`. If you simply request this value from your browser with a GET request and no SAML data, PingFed will show you a generic error template page. 
   If you have successfully POST'd the SAMLResponse to the right endpoint, you will see the actual SAMLResponse logged in the /pingfederate/log/server.log.